# Why isn't my ASP.NET deployment server using the configured environment name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I've deployed an ASP.NET web application to a test server we're using for UAT. I've set the ASP.NET Core Environment name to "UAT" using the following Powershell command...

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "UAT"
```

...and confirmed this setting using...

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

However, when I run the application I can see in `Startup` the `IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName` property returns "Production". Why would this be?

Comment: You run application from the same powershell window you set your variable in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the whole server for UAT, it makes sense to set that environment variable on machine level. Your current powershell command sets it only for current process, so it will work only if you run your application from the same powershell console (and will be lost when you close it). You can set it at machine level for example with this powershell command (you need to run console elevated, under admin, for this to work):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "UAT", "Machine")
```

You can set it to any value, not necessary to "predefined" ones like Production, Staging, Development.

Note that all user\machine level environment variables changes only take effect for new processes, it does not change them for already existing processes. So if you run your web application under IIS - you need to restart IIS for it to take effect. If you run it from cmd\powershell console - you need to restart console, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, I clearly wasn't setting at machine level before. But I've now done this and the app (run through IIS) is still using `EnvironmentName` Production. Same when I run in CMD like this: "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" .\MyProject.dll

Comment: You need to restart process for this to take effect. For example if you were running your "cmd" console, then you set environment variable in powershell, now you need to close your cmd console and reopen it to get new value of variable. Same with IIS.

Comment: You're quite right, I was restarting IIS using the Restart button in the UI, but it needed a full `iisreset /restart`. I think it'd be useful if you added this to your post for anyone in same position as me, then I'll mark as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

`'Staging'` is synonyms of `UAT` for many companies and sometimes is `pre-prod`   Use `staging` instead

[What is difference between testing environment and staging?](https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-testing-environment-and-staging)

from cmd or PowerShell 
you can use this:

```
>setx ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT "staging" /M
```

//be sure you got this message

```
     SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

or from Powershell only

```
$Env:ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT = "staging"
```

and run  it like the following

```
dotnet run --environment "Staging"
```

and if you want to check it use the following

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsStaging())
```

**Update**, in fact, you can custom your environment variable and check it like the following

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
            {
                if (env.IsEnvironment("UAT")
```

Comment: I assumed we were free to set any environment name we liked. Curious that the type of environments would be constrained. UAT and Staging are very different concepts to me. But let me try your suggestion and get back to you.

Comment: @getsetcode For many companies means the same thing from here https://www.quora.com/What-is-difference-between-testing-environment-and-staging

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I've now been sure to set the environment variable at machine level, but still same problem.